# cleaner code, concatenate calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, string-interpolation

im still fairly new to RoR, and as always looking for better, more efficient ways of coding. with the following line of code, is there possibly a better way of achieving the same result?

`= "#{schedule.time.to_s(:event_date) + " @ " + schedule.time.to_s(:event_time) + " - " + (schedule.time + schedule.duration.to_i.minutes).to_s(:event_time)}"`

which will output

`Fri, 31 Aug, 2012 @ 10:40 PM - 11:40 PM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide this complex line inside schedule helper, you can as well define schedule.end_time

```
module ScheduleHelper
  def schedule_time schedule
    html = ''
    html << schedule.time.to_s(:event_date)
    html << ' @ '
    html << schedule.time.to_s(:event_time)
    html << ' - '
    html << schedule.end_time.to_s(:event_time)
    raw html
  end
end

class Schedule
  def end_time
    self.time + this.duration.to_i.minutes
  end
end

<%= schedule_time schedule %>
```

Comment: using that method, i get `undefined local variable or method `schedule' for #<Schedule:0xafc6bb0>`

Comment: just edited one line from answer => `self.time + this.duration.to_i.minutes`. Anyways, its good to have end_time method. And what ever way you go, it would be better if you could define a helper method to it, which you can unit test later, and thats what basically helpers mean for. It not good to have such longer lines in views or for that matter anywhere.

Comment: with this code would it be possible to check if they have an end time or not?

Comment: that means where duration is specified or not? if duration is nil you can simply have `self.time + (this.duration || some_default_duration).to_i.minutes` or it could be `self.time + this.duration.to_i.minutes if duration \n ""`, you can return empty string which means no end-time

Answer (score 1):

not so sure if the time formatting could be done much better, but your string should be more like:

```
"#{schedule.time.to_s(:event_date)} @ #{schedule.time.to_s(:event_time)} - #{(schedule.time + schedule.duration.to_i.minutes).to_s(:event_time)}"
```

Answer (score 1):

First - throw away several pluses and braces, to achieve something like this:

```
= "#{schedule.time.to_s(:event_date)} @ #{schedule.time.to_s(:event_time)} - #{(schedule.time + schedule.duration.to_i.minutes).to_s(:event_time)}"
```

Also it may be useful to encapsulate it to helper if this consctruction is used in more than one place.